# How to make Selenium wait until javascript script finishes in Chromedriver (VBA)?

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, selenium, google-chrome

My question is pretty general, so I don't have any relevant code to show.
Basically, how does one go about making VBA wait until a Javascript script finishes in Selenium Chromedriver? I have an extension that hides/edits certain elements of a webpage and it takes a little bit to do its job, so my VBA script doesn't get the right element counts as of right now.
I've thought about it a bit, and if there isn't a straightforward way to do it, is there a way to wait until the number of elements that have certain attributes stops changing? It'd have the same effect.

Thanks in advance!